# How read every pixel of image and take couple of last bits from every color channel(RGBA)

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-bitmap

So i'm trying to get a byte array of compressed data in an image, the maker told me that I need to read every color channel.

Here's my code so far:

```
byte[] RGBAb = null;
for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) 
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) 
                {
                    int mask = 0xFF;
                    
                    Integer R = Math.abs(bitmap.getPixel(x, y) >> 16 & mask);
                    Integer G = Math.abs(bitmap.getPixel(x, y) >> 8 & mask);
                    Integer B = Math.abs(bitmap.getPixel(x, y) & mask);
                    Integer A = Math.abs(bitmap.getPixel(x, y) >> 24 & mask);
                    
                    byte Rb = R.byteValue();
                    byte Gb = G.byteValue();
                    byte Bb = B.byteValue();
                    byte Ab = A.byteValue();
                    
                    RGBAb = new byte[] { Rb, Gb, Bb, Ab};
                    
                    //System.out.println("Red" + R + "\n Red to bytes: " + Rb);
                    //System.out.println("Green" + G + "\n Green to bytes: " + Gb);
                    //System.out.println("Blue" + B + "\n Blue to bytes: " + Bb);
                    //System.out.println("Alpha" + A + "\n Alpha to bytes: " + Ab);
                    
                    System.out.println("RGBA Bytes COMBINED \n" + RGBAb);
                    
                }
            }
```

I dont know if it's outputting the right value.

This is the photo im reading:
[Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7mVr.jpg)

Comment: I see no byte array. And why do you think that we would know if it is outputting the right values? We dont even know what you wanna output. And also not what you get as output. You could post some log lines to show. Further as you are manupulating the four bytes of an integer you should output all values in hexadecimal notation as then you see what happens.

Comment: I updated it and the some of the byte returns negative.

Comment: Output all in hexadecimal notation to begin with. Otherwise you are blind. And there is no negative with hexadecimal notation.

Comment: And before you start shifting print `bitmap.getPixel(x, y)` in hexadecimal notation. Then you see what you handle.